# GVim not recognizing commands in plugin

Tags: sql, windows, vim

**How do I get gvim to recognize sqlcomplete.vim commands?**

I'm unable to use the [sqlcomplete.vim](http://ftp.stust.edu.tw/vim/runtime/autoload/sqlcomplete.vim) plugin. When running `:version` I get the following output:

[image]

and scrolling all the way to the bottom here is the rest of the output:

[image]

and the env variables:

```
:echo $VIM
c:\users\me\.babun\cygwin\etc\

:echo $HOME
H:\
```

Here is the output of `:scriptnames`:

[image]

When running the sqlcomplete.vim command such as `:SQLSetType sqlanywhere` the output I get is:

[image]

**How do I get gvim to recognize sqlcomplete.vim commands?**

Another piece of helpful information is the output of `:echo &rtp` :

```
H:\vimfiles,H:\.vim\bundle\Vundle.vim,H:\.vim\bundle\dbext.vim,H:\.vim\bundle\SQ
LComplete.vim,C:\Users\me\.babun\cygwin\etc\vimfiles,C:\Users\me\.babu
n\cygwin\etc\,C:\Users\me\.babun\cygwin\etc\vimfiles/after,H:\vimfiles/afte
r,H:\.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim,H:\.vim\bundle\Vundle.vim/after,H:\.vim\bundle\dbext
.vim/after,H:\.vim\bundle\SQLComplete.vim/after
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points you could check:

1. `:scriptnames` shows **plugin**\sqlcomplete.vim

But the link you provided points to .../vim/runtime/**autoload**/sqlcomplete.vim, there is no .../vim/runtime/**plugin**/sqlcomplete.vim, and the [version at vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1572) also doesn't contains a /plugin file:

```
install details
Copy sqlcomplete.vim to:
.vim/autoload/sqlcomplete.vim (Unix)
vimfiles\autoload\sqlcomplete.vim (Windows)

For documentation:
:h sql.txt
```

Maybe you have installed it incorrectly.

2. The file on your link has version 12 at its header, while the latest version is 15. Try updating to the latest version
3. Note that this plugin **does not define** the SQLSetType command.

You could check that by simple searching the file the on link. And on its header:

```
" Vim OMNI completion script for SQL
" Language: SQL
" Maintainer: David Fishburn <dfishburn dot vim at gmail dot com>
" Version: 15.0
" Last Change: 2013 May 13
" Homepage: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1572
" Usage: For detailed help
" ":help sql.txt"
" or ":help ft-sql-omni"
" or read $VIMRUNTIME/doc/sql.txt
```

Following `:help sql.txt`:

```
2.1 SQLSetType                  *sqlsettype* *SQLSetType*
--------------
For the people that work with many different databases, it is nice to be
able to flip between the various vendors rules (indent, syntax) on a per
buffer basis, at any time.  The ftplugin/sql.vim file defines this function: >
    SQLSetType
```

And scriptnames is **not** listing `ftplugin/sql.vim`